# How to calculate two sample $t$-test $p$-value in R

Tags: statistics

I have 2 independent datasets, and I know the following about each of them: mean, SD, and sample size. I calculated the t-statistic just fine

```
my.t.test<-function(mu1, mu2, sd1, sd2, n1,n2){
  t=(mu1-mu2)/sqrt((sd1)^2/n1+(sd2)^2/n2)
  return(t)
}
```

I know that the degrees of freedom is n1+n2-2, now I just need to calculate the p-value. I tried just `pnorm(t)` but that didn't seem like it was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  If the samples are both normal but with different variances, the degrees of freedom is not as you describe because you cannot use the pooled sample variance to estimate the population standard deviation.  There's a built in function to do such a test in either case of equal or unequal variances.

The test is `t.test()` in R.  See the help documentation.  The optional argument for the case of unequal variances is `var.equal = FALSE`.  It does not need you to state the sample means or variances; it just takes two vectors of data (not necessarily of the same length).  It also assumes normality, so if you want to check the normality assumption, use something like `shapiro.test()`.

Comment: And may I ask what that function is? I only know the mean, SD, and sample size. I don't know the actual values of each observation; that's why I didn't use the t.test function.

Comment: See the Wikipedia page for Welch's t test.  The appropriate degrees of freedom are given by Satterthwaite's approximation.  You then compare the test statistic against the student t distribution with the appropriate degrees of freedom and reject when the statistic exceeds the critical value.

Comment: The problem is I don't have the actual vectors containing the data I can pass into t.test. I only know the sample size, mean, and SD.

Comment: Did you see the Wikipedia page?  None of the calculations for the test statistic or the degrees of freedom require you to know the individual data.  The formulas are expressed in terms of the quantities you say you have.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But what I'm asking is how to find the p value in R. Not how to find the test statistic or d.f.

Comment: **You need the test statistic and the d.f. to find the $p$-value!**  The CDF for the student $t$ distribution in R is `pt()`.  Look it up in the help file.  Say you got a test statistic of 4.2, and the d.f. is 5.  Then for a two-tailed hypothesis test, you would just compute `2(1-pt(abs(4.2), 5))`.  For a one-tailed test, I assume you know how to adjust the command appropriately.  I cannot possibly make it any simpler for you.  Finally, this is a math forum.  Your question is specific to R and should be asked either in stats.SE or stackoverflow.com.  Not here.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.